# Read retrieved json data using jquery in View mvc 3

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, viewdata

I declared and serialized data on my View page

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCvs2012.Models.Employees>

 @{
    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var employees = @serializer.Serialize(ViewData["Employees"]);   
  }
```

Results when running the browser:

```
[{"FirstName":"Nancy","LastName":"Davolio","Title":"Sales Representative"}]
```

I want to present this data using jquery into a table like this:

```
<table id="employee">
<tr>
  <td>Nancy</td>
  <td>Davolio</td>
  <td>Sales Representative</td>
</tr>
...
</table>
```

Comment: Im lost why you are using JSON format to send C#/Razor data. Seems more sensible to pass your list to your view and render it with a for each loop.

Comment: Yes, I tried that method and it is a 100% , but I'm trying to find a way to display those data without refreshing the page and by just clicking on a button, you can have those data appended to a table in your view

Comment: OIC, consider using a partial view with child action for your report. Then request a new one with JQuery `.load()`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, There's a caching going on when using Partial View? and using jquery .load() you can get those cached data and store them on a var or something?

Comment: when you use a jquery `.load()`, it overwrites caching. I use .load() with partials for all incremental behaviors. Can be used to refresh a report or to add more data by passing a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to build your table. Something along the lines of

```
$var table = '<table>';
$.each(yourJson, function( index, value ) {
      $table += '<tr><td>' + value.FirstName + '</td><td>' + ...
});
$table += '</table>';
```

Comment: How can I put my serialized data(employees) on a var(yourJason)? that I can call from my jquery

Comment: I haven't used MVC in a while, _but_ you just need to store it as some sort of variable, then you can put it in. So like var data = @GetItFromYourController, then just call it as $.each(data ..